# How to safely exchange data between main and SceneKit threads

Tags: concurrency, scenekit

Inputs events are managed in the main thread, SceneKit renderer delegate executes in a dedicated SceneKit thread. There are some moments when we want to send data from the main thread to the renderer delegate in a safe way, and I couldn't find any way in the documentation.

A - We surely don't want to use dispatch queues or any other mechanism that could suspend the SceneKit thread if it wants to read the data while it happens that the main thread is modifying them. That could brake the FPS.

B - The Apple doc sometimes says that changing some node property from the renderer delegate or from elsewhere has different behaviors. For example `SCNPhysicsBody.velocity`:

> When invoked within a rendering loop method (any of the methods in the SCNSceneRendererDelegate protocol), or from any other code invoked from within such a method, reading the property returns the current result of the physics simulation, and setting the property immediately applies the change.
>
> When invoked at any other time, reading the property returns the last value set for the property, and setting the property does not take effect until the next pass through the rendering loop.

So it shows that something is sometime happening, but my tests showed that setting `SCNPhysicsBody.angularVelocity` from outside the rendering loop just doesn't work (the values are always reset for some reason). Besides, it is not clear what Apple did and when this is activated.

C - So I ended up doing something like that :

```
class MyDataToExchange { ... }

var dataToWrite:    MyDataToExchange? = MyDataToExchange()
var dataToExchange: MyDataToExchange? = nil
var dataToRead:     MyDataToExchange? = nil

>> In the main thread:

// Take the time to process events, build data in dataToWrite
    (...)

// When ready to send the data to SceneKit
dataToExchange = dataToWrite  // This **should** be "atomic"
// From this point on SceneKit can read the data
dataToWrite    = nil
// From this point on I can't do anything in the main thread and must wait for 
// dataToExchange to become nil again. I will ignore/store any event until I have
// something like
if dataToExchange == nil { 
    dataToWrite = MyDataToExchange() 
    // Do whatever
}


>> In the renderer thread:

if dataToExchange != nil {
    dataToRead     = dataToExchange
    dataToExchange = nil
    // From this point on, I can do whatever is needed with dataToRead, and the main
    // thread can build new data to send
}
```

I believe this is safe because copying references should be atomic, and there is only one thread working on one instance of MyDataToExchange at a time.
But I can hardly believe there is no simpler mechanism and that I have to re-invent something.

- Is that really Safe ?
- Is there any better/simpler way ?